# why the Value is nil although i created a new variable for the model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working on a ruby on rails project and I am new to it. I have created a model named Category and added properties `attr_accessor :name` in it.

Then to add a new Category to the database I wrote in rails console
`category = Category.new(:name => "GAMES")`.

After writing this I still get `("Category id = nil, name:nil..")`.

Then after that I did `category.save` the `id` number changes but the name field remains `nil`.

Well the code goes like this:

```
rails g model category name:string (in git hub)
```

Then in the ruby file

```
Class Category > ApplicationRecord
  attr_accessor :name
  has_many :posts
end
```

Then back to Github:

```
category = Category.new(:name => "Games")
category.save
```

The value of name remains `nil` after doing this.
Why is this happening. I am using Heroku git and O didnt commit and push the models after I created it. Is it because of that? or are there some other reasons?.

Please help Thank you

Comment: It'd be great if you add the code involved in the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Remove `attr_accessor :name` as it overrides ActiveRecord default behavior.

Comment: @Mannish While testing in console, do you get any other message?

Comment: @Mannish And, just to sure, you restarted you console session after the change, right?

Comment: i get a message Category id = 1, name = nil..but when i type category.name it gives me Games.

Comment: i almost started from rock bottom and finnaly got it. the nil came because the name i wrote was in double quote where as when i write it in single quote 'Games' then it show. Thank you

Comment: @Mannish Wow, that's really odd. Thanks for sharing! If you now change to double quoted again, do you get the error?